# Is there any method to make PDF print out nicely for highlighting on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing

This problem happens on Google Chrome but is also on the Mac, so I am not entirely sure if it is a Mac related issue or Chrome issue.

For some webpages, such as https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started Google Chrome can print it out as a PDF, but the first highlighting using Preview would show the highlighting is off. This has been happening for more than a year:

[image]

It doesn't happen if it is printed by Safari, but Safari sometimes has some issue such as the content column quite narrow.  Is there a way to make it print out suitable for highlighting if it is on Chrome?  It might be a Google Chrome issue or it might be somehow related to how macOS support printing but as a PDF file. Since printing as PDF is particular to Mac but not on Windows, so I am asking this on Ask Different.

Comment: Printing as PDF is also possible on Windows... Perhaps it is more to the default settings you have A4, Letter, Legal etc as well as what the printer expects...

Comment: Where does this highlighting come from? The webpage itself, or is this annotations to the PDF after creation?

Comment: we can print out a webpage as a PDF file, and then highlight it (using Preview). This is how some users (including me), to not print out a webpage on real paper, but just to print it out as a PDF and be able to highlight it for important notes on the page

Comment: Can you supply a sample PDF?  It may be that Chrome is offsetting the text from its true position somehow, or otherwise creating a difference between the display and the data.